# React-Router redirect through server

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-dom-server

So I'm working on a site that wants links with the following path:

```
localhost:3000/visit/:name
```

To redirect to an external url for example google.com?affiliateID=2. The redirect needs to be nofollow with status code 307.

The app is universal; server-side rendering using express & client-side react, both using a shared routes via react-router.

routes.js

```
<Route status={307} path="visit/:slug" />
```

server.js

```
app.use((req, res) => {
  match({routes, location: req.originalUrl}, (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
   if (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err.message)
   } else if (redirectLocation) {
    res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
   } else if (renderProps) {
    const html = renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps} />)

    const isAffiliateLink = renderProps.routes.filter((route) => {
     return route.status === 307
    }).length > 0

   if (isAffiliateLink) {
    return res.redirect(307, "http://google.com")
   }

   const markup = renderToStaticMarkup(<Document html={html} />)

   res.status(200).send("<!DOCTYPE html>" + markup)
  } else {
    res.status(404).send("Not Found")
  }
 })
})
```

here I'm checking if the requested route is the /visit/slug by checking the status, 307. If that is the case, it will redirect to the destination. This works.

What I struggle with now however is that I have hundreds of affiliate links, with different URLs and each with a corresponding slug.

What is the best way to programmatically input the right url for the right slug?
In the Route I can give a prop

```
<Route path="/visit/:slug" url="url.com" />
```

which I can access from server.js, but I'm not sure how to make that one dynamic depending on the slug.

Or should I do an API call to a database on server.js that has all the slugs and their corresponding URL?

Or is there a way I can pass a prop to the Route from a component that is used to click the link? Ie

```
<AffiliateLink slug={slug} url={url} />
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Got any solution. even I having this type of problem in my current project. if yes post your answer here which help us better